# access properties of widget inside canvas.create_window

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am having the following problem. I am making a tkinter GUI, and  I need to access an object that is inside a canvas, inside a Canvas.create_window widget, packed with some other objects. For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas()
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        f = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        f.pack()
        self.container = self.canvas.create_window(50,50, window = f)
        l = tk.Label(f, text='abc')
        e = tk.Entry(f, width = 5)
        l.pack()
        e.pack()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to edit the text of the l label (which is currently 'abc'), when some other event is triggered. I suppose I need to use canvas.itemconfig, but I can't find a way to pass to this function the correct reference to the label. Any Ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `itemconfigure` -- that is only for configuring canvas items. Your label is not a canvas item, it's just a normal tkinter widget that you access like any other widget. Save a reference, and then use the reference to call a method.

For example:

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.l = tk.Label(f, text='abc')
        ...
    def some_event_handler(event):
        self.l.configure(text="xyz")
```